# Short circuit problem (batteries getting HOT) within circuit

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor, reverse-polarity, dpdt

I am making a circuit with a simple 12 V DC motor in series with a normally open microswitch and on off switch connected to a DPDT switch to reverse the polarity of the motor. The first issue I had was to find a way to connect a microswitch to only work in the reverse position, and through trial and error, I connected the switch between the negative side of the battery and motor, this set up works however the batteries keep draining current (getting hot) I'd just like to ask what am I doing wrong, and is there any other method using the components used, I've attached a simple drawing (apologies for the quality).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGxqua.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I can't see the image, but make sure your switch doesn't short out the battery in any position.

Comment: Can you see the image now? The problem is that it's doing exactly what I require but just makes the batteries get to hot.

Comment: I think that the fact that it's doing what you want is a fluke. It's sheer chance. And it's not doing it the way it should. It's doing what you want by shorting something out

Comment: Your redrawn schematic is wrong. SW3 connects directly between the battery terminals, and works by shorting out the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the pinout of your DPDT switch it's difficult to say for sure, but from the image it appears you are indeed shorting out your battery through the switch. I also don't see how the microswitch is working. Can you try to redraw your circuit using standard schematic symbols? It will be much easier to see and understand the functionality of your current setup.

A standard motor reversal configuration using a DPDT switch is shown below:

[image]

Please provide some clarification of what you are trying to do with your microswitch. As described, it does not make much sense. If you intend for the motor to only run in reverse if the DPDT switch is set to "reverse" AND the microswitch is closed, then you can put the microswitch between the opposite corner terminals of the switch in the above graphic (replace one of the diagonal wires with the switch).

EDIT: Updated recommended circuit diagram:

[image]

Note that both micro switches are configured to be NC (normally closed).

Comment: iv'e tried as best i can to draw the schematic i have  posted it in the question, regards

Comment: So basically the vehicle must go forwards and reverse and i need the sw3 switch ( Normally open microswitch)  to only work when the motor is reversed if that makes sense, so when the dpdt is forwards the switch is disabled; in reverse switch can have effect.

Comment: You still don't explain *what* effect you want the microswitch to have...?

Comment: Ok, there's another problem, never put a potentiometer in series with a motor circuit. That's a good way of burning it out.

Comment: apologies, when in reverse the micro switch (sw3) should make the vehicle stop, hence stopping the movement of the motor, interrupting the whole circuit

Comment: Ok, so put a NC microswitch between two opposite-corner contacts as mentioned in my initial answer. The motor will operate normally when in the "forward" position, and will work normally in the "reverse" position until the microswitch is pressed (opened).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, could you show me this on my diagram, also how would you recommend i integrate the potentiometer?

Comment: What is the intent of the potentiometer? If you're trying to change motor speed, that really should be done using PWM. A resistance in series with the motor is rarely a good idea.

Comment: well yes, the main aim was to just slightly limit the motor speed and ok ill look into getting a PWM

Comment: @Mcccccc "PWM" stands for "pulse width modulation". It's not something you "get". You need a circuit that generates a series of pulses. The circuit should have something that lets you adjust the pulse width. Longer pulse width = faster motor speed. Shorter pulse width = slower motor speed.

Comment: Ah ok i wouldn't be able to do that, as with this project i have tight constraints e.g. no use of relays or memory storing devices the circuit i have constructed is basically the limit as far as components goes.

Comment: In that case, forget about adjusting motor speed. Also, what was the point of the second microswitch? New schematic on its way

Comment: Here is my circuit suggestion, based on your original circuit. I removed the POT though, because not only was it not going to do what you wanted it to do in this case, but it also wasn't connected correctly in the schematic. https://s7.postimg.org/jxeqt0vpn/2017_03_14_18_28_07_Circuit_Lab_Editing_Stack_E.png

Comment: Thankyou and thats just to temporarily disable the vehicle to allow it to be positioned. then when manually released the vehicle should be on its way

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I would have put it in series with the battery in that case, but it probably doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your DPDT switch to switch polarity to motor.  And put your microswitch on source side of battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb1KY8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Test with a meter to see if voltage changes polarity and circuit behaves as you want.